# Android Studio Signed APK for Google Map API v2

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I know this question was already ask 100, 1000-times, but still I have a problem with it and I already tried a lot by signing the application and to visualize the map after putting them in the store.

What I actually want is the following: Putting the android application in the store under "Alpha" version. This works without a problem, the application works, the only thing that doesn't work is the google map, its a white screen, I think the problem is that there is something wrong with the signed api key, but I don't know what.

Firstly I did the keystore with this dialog.

[image: Generated the release keystore]

Afterwards I generate the SHA1 value for the google map api key with this new keystore. Putting the SHA1 value into the console.developers.google.com link under credentials to generate a PUBLIC API ACCESS key under the following format: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX;PPP.PPPPP and then I generate a key and copied this in the manifest file.

[image: Generate SHA1 value for google map api key]

And finally I either generated a signed apk for the store or directly signed it by building it for the smartphone.

[image: Config 1-2]

But still it doesn't work. I don't know what the problem could be... Maybe one of you can help me.

Comment: "I think the problem is that there is something wrong with the signed api key" - can you describe why you came to this conclusion?

Comment: It's the only thing what makes the difference between the debug version and the released version and when I build it in release version I get this error in the logcat:  E/Google Maps Android API﹕ Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start for how to correctly set up the map.

Answer (score 1):

OK guys thanks for your help I found the error... Don't know how it came to this error but still I found it.

As you may know android studio will generate you an google_maps_api.xml file. When I opened the file there was the key written "ALZ...." but when I check in the multi languages place, there was written "YOUR_KEY_HERE", so something went wrong... After putting the key in the multi language place it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem (since the key generation was device specific). I don't know whether its the best answer or not but following solved my problem:
In Google Developer Console(after creating project and enabling apis), I generated a browser key without entering any ip and used that as my key.
That solved my issue.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but for a browser key I need a web page to enter to get a key and not the SHA1 value.

Comment: just don't enter anything where it asks for url or something and create a key. You will find a key generated.do tell me if not

Comment: works for debug build variant but not for release build variant :/